# What might Fn+X do?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, function-keys

On my laptop keyboard all <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>key</kbd> are labeled in blue. However <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> is not labeled and <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> - <kbd>Z</kbd> (other then <kbd>X</kbd>) prints out that letter. Its not printing <kbd>X</kbd> so what might it be doing?

Comment: What make / model of laptop? They tend to have thier own setups with regards to keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fn+X is used by a few vendors as a Diagnostic mode. It's meant to be used during boot only to get in and out of diagnostic mode. Otherwise does nothing.

Dell is one vendor I remember specifically using this combination.

Comment: This is a dell. That sounds right. How do i get into diagnostic mode? From a simple google it seems i need to use the dell CD or HD (xp only?) if i havent nuked them to have a XP/7 partition

Comment: I don't own a Dell anymore. Been a long time. But assuming Fn+X doesn't get you into system diagnostic mode during boot, it will be used instead solely to get you out of it, when you are forced into diagnostic mode during a failed boot. And you are right, of course. Because this Fn combo is mapped, you don't get a X when used during normal operation. These combos are hardwired into the system.

Answer (score 0):

If `Fn[a-z^x]` works but `Fnx` doesn't, it might just be a problem with the keyboard.  (Ie: pressing `Fn` stops the keybord from noticing when `x` is pressed.)  It wouldnt be nearly the stangest bug i've heard of.

Comment: what would be stranger :p thats pretty darn strange to me

Comment: [Magic](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/magic-story.html), for one.

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally pressed Fn+X on accident while drawing and it made my speakers buzz and my music I was playing stop for one second. Other than that it seemed to do nothing.